# Count of Maximum - CodeChef

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge

I'm doing an easy problem in codechef. Here's the problem statement for [maxcount:](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXCOUNT/)

> Given an array A of length N, your task is to find the element which
>   repeats in A maximum number of times as well as the corresponding
>   count. In case of ties, choose the smaller element first.

OK, I cheated. I used `std:map` because I want to play with it. Please review my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

int main() {
    int test_cases{};
    std::cin >> test_cases;
    for (auto i = 0; i < test_cases; ++i) {
        std::map<int,int> count;
        std::size_t size{};
        std::cin >> size;
        int x{};
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            std::cin >> x;
            count[x] = ++count[x];
        }
        int number{};
        int numberCount{};
        for (auto& i : count) {
            if (i.second > numberCount) {
                number = i.first;
                numberCount = i.second;
            } else if (i.second == numberCount) {
                if (i.first < number) {
                    number = i.first;
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        std::cout << number << " " << numberCount << '\n';
    }
}
```

How can I make this better and faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify:

```
        count[x] = ++count[x];

        // Why not just;
        ++count[x];
```

Variable name length:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < test_cases; ++i) {
```

Have you ever tried searching for all occurrences of the variable `i` in the resulting loop. The number of false positives will be a pain in the arse. Name your loop variables so you can find them easily.

Hiding variables names:

```
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
```

Though not technically illegal. This becomes a maintenance problem. It's OK for you today as you just wrote the code. But for anybody else (or you in years time) this is can be a pain. Try and give your variables unique meaningful names (self documenting code is a brilliant practice but it requires variable names to be meaningful).

The whole loop where you search for the largest repeat:

```
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
```

This can be done inline while you were counting. I would not have a second loop to work it out after the fact.

I would simplify this condition:

```
} else if (i.second == numberCount) {
            if (i.first < number) {

// I find it easier to read as:

} else if (i.second == numberCount) && (i.first < number) {
```

This seems a bit redundant:

```
        } else {
            continue;
        }
```

Personally I think initializing integers with `{}` looks terrible (and is slightly confusing).

```
std::size_t size{};

std::size_t size = 0;  // Much easier to read.
```

Whats the point in initizliaing a variable just before you write over it?

```
    std::size_t size{};   // Why initialize it here
    std::cin >> size;     // Only to trash the initialization here.
```

#### Address Comments:

```
    int number{};
    int numberCount{};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

        std::cin >> x;
        std::size_t&  countV = count[x];

        ++countV;

        if (countV > numberCount || (countV == numberCount && x < number))
        {
            number      = x;
            numberCount = countV;
        }
    }
```

Comment: std::size_t& countV = count[x]; didn't work for me because it looks like we can't initialise an int into an unsigned reference? Compiler says "invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::size_t& {aka unsigned int&}' from expression of type 'std::map<int, int>::mapped_type {aka int}'"

Comment: @morbidCode: Not going to do all the work for you. Think about it a bit,

Comment: I thought about it, and I fixed it. I just thought you made a bug.

Comment: I did. But not worth worrying about (that is what compilers do).

Answer (score 2):

Few remarks:

- The variable `i` of the testcase loop is not use and it is masked by the next `i` loop, you could simply use a `while loop` to not use any extra variable
- It would be better to declare `x` inside the for loop, since it is only use here.
- the line `count[x] = ++count[x]` is extremely confusing and a minor modification (`count[x] = count[x]++`) is an undefined behaviour. You should simply use `++count[x]`.
- Since map is an ordered container your `else if` is useless.
- Also doing just a `else{continue}` at the end of the loop is useless.
- You do not need to use `{}` to default initialise your variables.
- `number` should be initialised with meaningful value
- your code does not handle the case where the number of element is 0

Here is the code with my suggested improvements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    int test_cases;
    std::cin >> test_cases;
    while(test_cases--) {
        std::map<int,int> count;
        std::size_t size;
        std::cin >> size;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            int x;
            std::cin >> x;
            ++count[x];
        }
        int number;
        int numberCount = 0;
        for (auto& i : count) {
            if (i.second > numberCount) {
                number = i.first;
                numberCount = i.second;
            }
        }

        //if(numberCount == 0)
        //does something to handle the empty collection

        std::cout << number << ' ' << numberCount << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `it could be a good idea to use using namespace std` Nope bad idea: -1 As this contradicts every other code review done on this site. Its not the fact that the code is simple but it ingrains a bad habit that will cause accidents when writing real code. Remove it and I will remove the -1.

Comment: In fact I will give you a +1 for a case that I missed `your code does not handle the case where the number of element is 0`

Comment: I understand the argument, I will edit my answer.

Comment: int number = 0; - but if there is no elements, the user might think 0 is a real element because 0 can also be an element in the map right? Isn't setting numberCount to 0 then handle the case if numberCount remains 0 (no elements) after the loop better? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Nope you are right, I confused number and numberCount